# Linq using IsNullOrEmpty

Tags: linq

I am trying to check if a field is Null or Empty.

I have the following script:

```
  return db.Clients.Where(a => string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.ClientName) == false)
                   .OrderBy(a => a.ClientName);
```

It seems to work as expected. I was wondering if the above is the most efficient or if there may be some gottchas that I may not be aware of in using what I have above that may lead to issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, String.IsNullOrEmpty cannot be translated, therefor it can be faster to check for null and empty manually and seperately.

Comment: What do you mean *String.IsNullOrEmpty cannot be translated*? would be great if you provide code.

Comment: Sorry, writing on my mobile, I mean str != null && str.Length > 0

Comment: so, I'm back on my laptop. what I mean is the following: according to your markup I think you are using Linq2SQL and if so, the library does not translate this function to SQL but instead selects all rows from the db and executes the filter in code. if you write `str != null && str.Length > 0` it can be translated to `str is not null and len(str) > 0`.